# LED ceiling light with mismatch driver

Tags: led-strip, led-driver, leakage-current

I am new to the forum, so please forgive me if I am asking a stupid question or posting the wrong thing at the wrong place.

I recently bought a Led ceiling light online that comes with a remote control which allowed me to change the light temperature and brightness. However, I have noticed that if I used the remote to turn off the light, the light still glow (dim, but enough to notice and bother me at night…) If I use the wall switch, this will not happen (but doing so kind of defeated the feature of the dimmable light remote control). Based on what I searched so far, I figured that this is probably a mismatch of the controller and the LED strip. My ceiling light is supposed to be a 24W light, but on the controller, it said (36-48w)x2. So I am guessing that they have gave me the light with the incorrect controller installed…. The thing is, If I return the item, the postage would probably cost me at least half the price of the light, so it is really not worth returning…. So I am looking at ways to fix this rather than returning it. I have tried to switch the L and N wire  that goes into the controller (just in case the switch was on the wrong side), but it made no difference ☹ After reading online, I noticed that I might be able to put a resistor into the circuit to fix this, but I am not too sure where I should install it, and what would be a safe value of resistor to try out for. It would be great if anyone could shed some light on my problem.

I have attached a picture of my ceiling light, and a close up picture of the controller (the writing is in Chinese though). Each of the led strip are 2835 2b4C x2.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give a link to product documentation or at least where you got it from?

Comment: I bought this on Taobao. The link to the actual purchase page is gone :( (The seller have took down the item it seems). But there are exact same item that are being sold. The link below is one of them. But to be honest, it doesn't really provide much info
https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=606479012289&ns=1&abbucket=1#detail

Answer (score 1):

> Based on what I searched so far, I figured that this is probably a mismatch of the controller and the LED strip. My ceiling light is supposed to be a 24W light, but on the controller, it said (36-48w)x2. So I am guessing that they have gave me the light with the incorrect controller installed….

No, that is the correct controller for the lights. These are constant current LEDs (no resistors are present in the light strips), which means the driver generates the current needed to drive the LEDs. If it was generating too much current, the diodes would burn out quickly.

Since this is a constant current driver, the "0.17A" is the current, and the 36-48 is probably the range of voltages the driver can produce.

> So I am looking at ways to fix this rather than returning it. I have tried to switch the L and N wire that goes into the controller (just in case the switch was on the wrong side),

You should never do this due to the risk of electrical shock, especially with cheaply made electronics like this.

> After reading online, I noticed that I might be able to put a resistor into the circuit to fix this

Since this is a constant current supply, putting resistors in series will just cause the supply to put out more voltage to overcome the resistance. To solve this problem you probably need to replace the LED driver with a different one that is better designed.

Answer (score 0):

Only do this if you are not scared of experimenting and can solder.

### Solution #1

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffqlW4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A CC generator might not be able to be programmed to 1% minimum and this is too bright.

In order to reduce 170 mA for both strings or 85mA /string  dummy loads of  a power resistor must be shunt on A & B strings to absorb min. CC drive.

Assuming CC minimum of 10% of 85mA or 8.5mA at 24V approx for string of 4P8S array *2 colors
Dummy load is 24V/8.5mA=2.8k
[image]

### - depending on how bright is DIM (Off) you can adjust R up to 10K or 24V/10k = 2.4mA of dummy load.

Comment: Thanks :D I am willing to experiment, as I am now very much stuck with this light lol. So just to clarify, I should solder 2 resistors for the whole light? (or is that 2 per strip, so 8 in total?) 

Dim (off) is actually pretty bright lol it managed to cast a visible shadow of my hand on the wall even when it is like 1.5-2m away from my hand....

Comment: So my 10% estimate might not bee too far off

Comment: oh, then I guess I should try for 5k then. Just to clarify, should I do 2 resistors for the whole light or 2 per strip (8 in total)?

Comment: 2 for all  .......

Comment: Thanks Tony, I will give this a try tomorrow when I got my hands on some resistors :D

Comment: you can also get a bunch of 10K's or  a 1k in series with a 10k Pot.  or a bunch of 1k's in series

Answer (score 0):

OK, you gave [the link](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=606479012289&ns=1&abbucket=1#detail), unfortunately all the Chinese text is in pictures, which Google Translate can not parse. Still... this confirms an important construction detail:

[image]

This is designed to be mounted on a ceiling. Hot air rises, so we can't count on convection inside the enclosure to carry heat away from the LEDs (ie, down) and through the plastic diffuser ; hot air will stay up. Thus all the heat will be dissipated through the back of the luminaire. Mounting it against a ceiling will result in zero airflow against the back of the metal enclosure. So there is absolutely no way it can do 24 Watts (or even worse, 2x24W if both LED color temperature are on) without overheating... and the driver, which is rated for an ambient temperature of 45°C, is going to fry very soon.

A possible fix would be to mount it 50mm away from the ceiling by using longer screws. But it's still gonna run quite hot. I bet there is no thermal paste behind these MCPCBs...

In a better design, the LEDs would be mounted inside the aluminium profiles (they can be seen in the above picture) which would act as a heat sink in free air, just like in an edge-illuminated LED panel.

So don't feel too guilty about hacking this thing.

Now that wasn't an answer to your question, just advice on how not to have it self-destruct in a few months due to overheating.

I agree with Tony, you can put two resistors, one for each LED color, in parallel with the strips. The most convenient place seems to be on the pins of the unused connector at the end:

[image]

One resistor between "A" and "+" and the other resistor between "B" and "+".

If the connector is female, you can stick the resistor legs into it to experiment.

If your soldering iron isn't powerful enough to heat the MCPCB you can always rip the plastic shell of the connector off and solder resistors to the pins.

Note Tony's resistor value which draws 8.5mA will result in about half a watt power draw when the light is off. So you will probably want to replace the driver with a more "user friendly" one... no hurry, you'll have this opportunity when it fries I guess

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I will give this a try tomorrow when I get my hands on some resistors :D

Comment: peufeu  1/2W is worst cast dim to 10% but most likely Dim to 1% thus power loss is cheaper than new twin remote PWM power source of unknown quality and maximum current that must be matched exactly. (so easier said than done) Also open ceiling cutout is safe.